# Convert MathType and MS Word Equations equations to LaTeX

Tags: word-to-latex

I'm a programmer and writing application for local math community. It's web application and I'm using `MathJax` Plugin in it and `LaTex` format for mathematical equations. Most of the mathematicians are using `MS Word` (2007 or 2010) and have math papers and formulas in `MS Word` usually written in `MathType`.

Is there any easy and free offline tool to convert `MathType` and `MS Word` equations to `LateX`, so they can convert `MathType` formulas and input `LaTeX` formulas to my web application? I've found some tools and plugins for `MS Word`, but some of them have problems working on `64bit Windows`, others are commercial. Thanks for help.

Comment: doesn't mathtype have latex export? I'm sure it has mathml export (which also works as input to mathjax). I assume you mean mathtype, from word 2007 onwords there's also the possibility of the equations being in words native math zones...

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle! You are right, MathType has its own conversion. I think it was a bug in my MathType installation. I reinstalled it and the ribbon menu appeared in the MS Word

Comment: I don't understand your words: "Most of the mathematicians are using MS Word 2007 and 2010 and have math papers and formulas in MS Word". This is unimaginable for me. Most of the mathematicians around me are using TeX.

Comment: @wipet, LaTeX is not so well-known in place where I live. People usually use Microsoft Word for writing papers, and Equation tool in MS Word for writing/drawing equations. There are some who use MathType.

Comment: I mentioned TeX (in general) no specially LaTeX in my comment. Unfortunately, TeX and LaTeX are not distinguish by most people :(.

Comment: MathJax is off-topic as it is not TeX.

Comment: This is two different questions. MathType and Word equations are not the same, so the answers will be different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MathType can make a conversion to LaTeX(and many other formats) right out of the box. It adds its own ribbon menu in Word 2010. You can find conversion menu there.
[image: MathType Ribbon]

[image: MathType Conversion Tool]

Comment: Are there any alternatives? What if I have *.doc or *.docx files and I use Linux?

Comment: This is definitely the most elegant solution, I used this tip and successfully convert all formula in my docx into mediawiki format and then i used pandoc to convert the whole file into mediawiki page(with html unescape tools).

Comment: In this dialog box, first checkbox is for mathtype or equation editor equations. When I try to convert equation editor equations it doesn't convert. Only mathtype equations is getting converted. It doesn't capture equation editor equations

Comment: In the current version of Word 365, there's a LaTeX button in the Conversions section of the Equations tab. Then when you copy the equation, it will be pasted as LaTeX.