# Converting word file containing equations to LaTeX file using pandoc

Tags: equations, pandoc, msword, convert

I have a word file which contains many mathtype equations as objects. I am trying to convert the file to LaTeX using pandoc with following command, but I am not receiving the equations in tex file

```
pandoc -s -f docx Document1.docx -o Document2.tex
```

Is it possible to convert a docx file to tex file containing equation objects. If yes, kindly let me know how. And if not, is there any easy alternate?

thanks

Comment: No experience myself but this is what my search brought up: [mathtype](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233963/convert-mathtype-and-ms-word-equations-equations-to-latex)

Comment: Two notes to clarify vaettchen's answer.

First, the article linked is correct, but specific to MathJax. You probably want to choose "LaTeX 2.09" from the list shown in the screen shot shown in the article.

Second, the equations and their placement are only as good as the author's techniques. If the author used copy & paste to get them into Word, they'll all translate into LaTeX as display equations. If the author used proper techniques for inserting inline MathType equations, they'll be delimited properly in LaTeX.

Comment: thanks @vaettchen, it helped me. Bob: yes you are right, i have to format all equations correctly after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, take a look at [*Word2TeX* by Chikrii](https://www.chikrii.com/products/word2tex/)