# How to Convert Native MS Word 2016 Equations to Latex?

Tags: equations, msword, word-to-latex

I use the **native MS Word (2016) Equation Editor**, like this
[image: the Native MS Word Equation Editor]

**rather than MathType**, because it's more convenient to perform equation editing, like copying part of an equation or simplifying an expression with Word.

I have been performing mathematical derivation with word. Now, **I have loads of equations in MS Word, and I want to compose my manuscripts with Latex**, obviously because the latter has more impressive typesetting styles. I have installed the Texlive 2019.

**Is there any solution or tool to convert equations edited by the Native Equation Editor of MS to Latex?**

Any comments are most welcomed.

Best

Charles.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233963/convert-mathtype-and-ms-word-equations-equations-to-latex).

Comment: Just retype them in LaTeX, learn in the process,
and never use that word equation editor ever again.
You'd be surprised how mush easier and faster it is.

Comment: Thanks @g.kov. You know, I don't  use MS Word for composition. I do symbolic calculation with MS Word equation editor. And I find MS Word equation editor is quite convenient for this task, compared with MathType or even Latex. But I want to use Latex for publication to present my calculation in MS Word, which is just what Latex is good at.

Comment: Thanks for your warm welcome @M.AlJumaily. I have read that answer before. But no equation is edited by MathType in my MS word, and the "Convert Equations" button is grey. Plus, a comment "Only mathtype equations is getting converted. It doesn't capture equation editor equations" is found at your link. It seems it doesn't work with equations created by Equation Editor of MS word. Thank you again.

Comment: How I would do it -- write parsers for options (1) and (2). Options: (1) The `OMath` object traversed with VBA to extract the items and their relationships and then build-up the Latex version; (2) the `document.xml` already contains the items and their relationships, so only a `xslt` transform needs to be written; (3) the Latex-code-to-Equation-Editor-code button can be reversed to convert EE format back to Latex format - a feature-request can be made for this, to do it the simplest way.  (4) You could use a service, e.g. (via Google) http://www.wordtolatex.com/

Comment: @Cicada I worked with the `OMath` object with VBA and the experience was not very good, it's slow and ,of course, hard to debug compared with the other mainstream programming languages such as C++ or Python. And I suppose your second method is a good idea.

Comment: @C.K. Plus the specs seem to change without notice, or take ages to be enhanced. Anyway, the services look to be fairly popular.